# Visual Studio Code не видит пути к псевдонимам - alias

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, импорт, vite, tsconfig

При попытке перейти по **import** в **VSCode** выдает ошибку: **Не удалось открыть редактор, так как файл не найден**.

Я использую **Vite**. В настройках указал **alias** и так же указала в **tsconfig**, но это не помогло.

Процесс сборки/разработки работает корректно, но переключаться по файлам где используется псевдонима - не могу.

**vite.config.ts**

```js
import {
  defineConfig,
  loadEnv
} from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import path from 'path';

const {
  NODE_ENV
} = process.env;
const nameDevelopment: string = 'development';
const isDev = NODE_ENV === nameDevelopment;

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/styles'),
    },
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
      // generateScopedName: '[hash:base64:5]',
      generateScopedName: isDev ? '[local]__[hash:base64:5]' : '[hash:base64:5]',
      // generateScopedName: "prefix-[name]-[hash]",
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: true,
    host: true,
  },
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: function({
          name
        }) {
          if (/\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/img/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/\.css$/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/css/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }

          if (/.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)/.test(name ? ? '')) {
            return 'assets/fonts/[name]-[hash][extname]';
          }
          // default value
          // ref: https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputassetfilenames
          return 'assets/[name]-[hash][extname]';
        },
      },
    },
  },
  // Функция которая поможет решить проблему путей
  experimental: {
    renderBuiltUrl: function(filename: string, {
      hostId,
      hostType,
      type
    }: {
      hostId: string,
      hostType: 'js' | 'css' | 'html',
      type: 'public' | 'asset'
    }) {
      // console.log(arguments);
      if (type === 'asset') {
        if (hostType === 'css') {
          const stringRemove = 'assets';
          const stringLength = stringRemove.length;
          const stringPresence = filename.indexOf(stringRemove);
          if (-1 !== stringPresence) {
            console.log('..' + filename.substring(stringLength));
            return '..' + filename.substring(stringLength);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

**tsconfig.json**

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    // Custom setting
    // "baseUrl": "src",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@styles": ["src/*"],
    },
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

[image: code]